# iOS Fill use app data (strings, ints, images, etc) to fill out a pdf form and email it

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf

So I've got this idea for a project and am looking for some solutions on how to complete it. Right now I have an iphone app set up to take in a bunch of user information and an image of a signature they draw. I have a pdf waiver that needs to be populated with this data and the signature. Is there any way to overlay this data on the form? Is there a way to create an html document with the form as the background and then the data laid over the top with css?

If this is possible, then what's the best way to get that new pdf or html page to a website/folder/email.

Would appreciate any help with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For reference and theoretical explanations.. you can check Apple page https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html

Some nice tutorials:

- http://www.raywenderlich.com/6581/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1
- http://www.ioslearner.com/convert-html-uiwebview-pdf-iphone-ipad/
- http://www.ioslearner.com/generate-pdf-programmatically-iphoneipad/